# How to remove gpu saphire r9 390 from motherboard Asus H97 Anniversary

Tags: motherboard, troubleshooting, gpu

I'm not sure this is the right stack exchange place but I haven't found a better one.

I am unable to remove the gpu from the mobo, no matter what. I've heard it has a lever on the right side, which is supposed to be pushed down, but I have no way of reaching it. I feel like I've already applied too much pressure and might be breaking something, specially the part of the mobo where the gpu is inserted seems to be lifting now when I try to pull out the r9.

I did some photos that I hope help, I don't know what else to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0DuH.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoqIS.jpg

thanks in advance

Comment: The R9 390 is an external GPU, it can be removed, like any other PCI-E GPU on the market.

Comment: I just yank them things out like anything else.  Already out half way.

Comment: I know it can be removed, I don't know how it's done without breaking the mobo @Ramhound :S

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with out half way @SiXandSeven8ths